# How can I make a certain keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcuts

How can I make a keyboard shortcut so if I press AA it will do Ă and if I do aa it will do ă for Windows 10?

Comment: In what program in Windows 10? While you can configure CTRL+ and SHIFT+ and ALT+ keyboard shortcuts in Windows 10, to auto-correct "AA" into something else, you'll probably need to be doing that in specific programs. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want it to work for all programs

Comment: How will you type "Aaron"?

Comment: Well I won't be spelling Aaron "AAron will I?

Comment: It's a lot of aardvark to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to enter letters in languages other than English. Add a new input method or keyboard layout like *Romanian*.

Check this out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdropr.html

Comment: How do I add a new input method?

Comment: Press Win + S, search for 'language', go to 'region and language', 'Add a language', and follow the prompt.